# bypass login code php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with mycode '=''or'

```
$connect= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (isset($_POST["sub"])){
    $userr =$_POST["username"];
    $passs =$_POST["password"];
    $password = hash('sha256', $passs);
    $query="select * from user WHERE username='$userr'AND password='$password'";    

    $run=mysqli_query($connect,$query);

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
    {
         header("Location: index.php"); 
        $_SESSION['username']=$userr;
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $pri ='<center><br/> error </center>';
    }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

so when anyone doing bypass using `'=''or'` it will go to index.php

I don't know really how to fix it ..

Comment: Yeah you should NOT use `$userr` directly in your query. The bypass is call sql injection, Use prepared statements or at least escape your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just properly escape the `$userr` and `$password` variables for using in sql statement like this:

```
 $query="select * from user WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $userr)."' AND password='". mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $password)."'";
```

You can lookup php mysqli sql injection for more information.

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php then you can adjust your answer accordingly. What you posted will not work. I can't see why your answer was accepted, yet alone upvoted. Sorry, but that's just the simple truth of the matter.

Comment: Thanks, fixed mysqli_real_escape_string parameters.